# NSURLSessionDownloadTask is giving me unknown error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

From my cocoa static library project test case, I am hitting downloadtask using resume api of NSURLSessionDownloadTask, It is throwing error 
NSError *   domain:

```
@"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709551615
@"NSErrorFailingURLKey" : @"valid url"  
@"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"unknown error"
```

Same If I am trying in single view application, It is working fine after setting permission allow arbitrary loads to true.

There is no info.plist in cocoa static project, when I add some tests then I can see this info.plist but this points to test target.

Please help me on this!

Comment: It looks like your error code is `NSURLErrorUnknown = -1`, but in unsigned integer variable.